# Applying transitivity to digraphs question.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

**QUESTION:**

Consider all possible forms of a digraph with 2,3,4...n vertices.

Now let f(A) be the number of edges in A.

Also, let A^2 be the transitive of A, A^3 the transitive of A twice, A^4 the transitive of A three times, and so on.

Prove that f(A), f(A^2), f(A^3),.... f(A^n) converges to a single number, ie doesn't oscillate.

**ATTEMPT:**

I tried to prove it by cases with 2 vertices so far (16 digraphs) and it holds true that f(A), f(A^2), f(A^3),.... f(A^n) convergers to a single number at each case. With just 3 vertices, there are hundreds of cases so proving this concept onward by cases isn't time-efficient. That being said, I don't know how to move forward so any tips or advice would be really appreciated.

**Note:**

I am still fairly new to upper-level math so I apologize in advance for any way undesirable way I format or tag this post. Thank you for reading! <3

Comment: In the end, what was the solution? Could you write an answer yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unluckily, I'm not coming up with anything at the moment. Here are a few properties, maybe they help:

Let $ G= (V,E) $ be a graph. Let's define the transitivity-operation as

$f((V,E)) := (V,E')$, with $E':= \{(x,y)\in V^2\mid \exists a\in V: (x,a),(a,y)\in E \}$

The key property is that if 
$$x_1\to x_2\to ...\to x_n$$
 is a path in $G$, then 
$$x_1\to x_3\to ...\to x_{n-1}$$
 is a path in $f(G)$.

Let's call $x\to y$ path connected, if there exists some path $x\to y$.

- If at some iteration a path connection $x\to y$ is lost, then it is impossible to restore it.
- The path connection only is maintained into the next iteration if there is a path of even length from $x$ to $y$.
- For a path connection $x\to y$ to never be lost, one needs to be able to construct an arbitrarily long path from $x\to y$ (in $E$) with even length. This is possible exactly if there's a path $x\to y$ that passes through a circle with an odd number of vertices.
- An edge $x\to y$ will exist permanently after some iteration exactly if we can create a path of length $2n$ for all $n\ge k$ for some $k$.

Partial result: Any graph $G$ without odd cycle has $$\lim_{n\to\infty} M( f^n(G)) =  0$$

Partial result:

Let $P$ be the adjacency matrix of the graph. Then we have $$(P^n)_{i,j} >0 \Leftrightarrow \text{There's a path from $i$ to $j$ with length } n$$

Especially this means that $M(f(G^n))$ converges exactly if the number of zero-fields in $P^n$ is at some point constant.

Comment: Hello there, thank you for your response. Question though, part [1] is pretty easy, I found that f(A) <= (n+1)^2 for n >= 0. But [2] is where I am confused, how would I go about proving that f(A^n) to f(A^(n+1)) may increase, but never decrease?

Comment: @John Can it ever happen, that by applying transitivity to a, an edge disappears?

Comment: I think so? Example: given A with three vertices a,b,c and edges: {(a,b), (a,c), (b,d), (c,d)}, hence f(A) = 4. Applying transitivity, A^2 will have {(a,d)}, hence f(A^2)= 1. Of course continuing on this example, we would get that the pattern converges to 0. I guess I'm concerned about a possibility that since applying transitivity to a can make an edge disappear, how can I know that an edge wouldn't disappear much further down the chain (A^(n) to A^(n+1))?

Comment: Try to take a general graph, pick some edge of this graph. Then look at what you can say if you use the definition of transitivity on this general graph, and look what you can say about the result. If [2] is indeed true, then you can find a logical chain that uses your graph, the definition of transitivity and somehow comes to the conclusion, that the graph, when you used transitivity on it, still contains the edge we picked out at the start.

Comment: Wouldn't this not apply for all cases though (as seen in my example where say the edge (a,b) isn't seen past A)?  :/                                                                               
 Also, as a side note, thank you so much for giving me your time, I appreciate the help.

Comment: I'd have to see the precise definition of $A^n$ that you use.

Comment: I guess that's part of my confusion in that I don't have a general equation for A^(n). I have a general equation for the max f(A^n) = (n+1)^2. I followed some tutorials online and was able to prove that (n+1)^2 only increased or stayed the same, and thus impossible to decrease. But would proving the monotone convergence theorem for the equation describing the maximum edges (again, f(A^n) = (n+1)^2) only prove that there is a monotonic relationship between f(A), f(A^2), f(A^3),.... f(A^n) **only if** A, A^2, A^3...A^n have all maximal edges in the digraph.

Comment: The monotone convergence theorem would only work if the sequence would be monotone increasing. It then would say that the sequence converges to a maximum - but it gives no hint about what the maximum actually is.  However, that approach is mistaken, as I've thought about a different definition of transitivity

Comment: Do you allow self-loops?

Comment: Yes, self-loops are allowed.